# Install specific dependencies from pyproject.toml

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) package manager for python. I would like to install only 2 specific dependencies from *dev* dependency list - `flake8` and `black`. How it can be done?

My `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-app"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^23.7.0"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
pytest = "^7.4.0"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
```

I would like to avoid typing `flake8` and `black` package versions manually in bash console (something like `poetry add black=^23.7.0` command), because the version is already specified in `pyproject.toml` file.